# can a VM sniff plaintext network from another VM on the same VMware ESX host?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-server, esx

can a VM sniff plaintext network traffic from another VM on the same ESX host? we are concerned about a rouge VM sniffing traffic from our app VMs that will be communicating between themselves over http and JDBC.